# Which practice is best for handling HTML Events in Angular? Angular event binding or RxJS fromEvent function?

Tags: angular, rxjs

In Angular the most common and easy practice to handle HTML event, it is a simple event binding, but when logic become more complex, it is rational to use RxJS operators.

Let's see at two boilerplate examples:

[Live code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cqjstp?file=src/app/app.component.html)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-native-handler',
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let user of users">{{ user }}</li>
    </ul>

    <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <label>
        Name:
        <input type="text" formControlName="name">
      </label>

      <input type="submit" [disabled]="form.invalid">
    </form>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./native-handler.component.css']
})
class NativeHandlerComponent implements OnInit {
  form = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
  });

  users: string[] = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  onSubmit() {
    let name = this.form.controls.name.value;

    this.users.push(name);

    this.form.reset();
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-rxjs-handler',
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let user of users">{{ user }}</li>
    </ul>

    <form #formEl [formGroup]="form">
      <label>
        Name:
        <input type="text" formControlName="name">
      </label>

      <input type="submit" [disabled]="form.invalid">
    </form>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./rxjs-handler.component.css']
})
class RxjsHandlerComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('formEl') formEl: ElementRef;

  form = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
  });

  users: string[] = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    fromEvent(this.formEl.nativeElement, 'submit')
      .pipe(tap(() => this.onSubmit()))
      .subscribe();
  }

  onSubmit() {
    let name = this.form.controls.name.value;

    this.users.push(name);

    this.form.reset();
  }
}
```

In the first example, we don't have flexibility to do an extra async operations, unless we won't create another `Observable` inside `onSubmit()` function and subscribe to it double (first time when we do the event binding and second when we subscribe inside `onSubmit()` function).

On another hand, in the second example, we can `pipe()` whatever async strategy we want (`switchMap`, `concatMap`, `mergeMap` and etc) and we don't need to create any extra `Observable`. For example:

```
fromEvent(this.formEl.nativeElement, 'submit')
  .pipe(
    takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$),
    tap(() => this.onSubmit()),
    concatMap(() => this.http.post('/api/user', { name })),
    concatMap(() => this.storageSerivce.push(name)),
    catchError(...)
    ...
  )
  .subscribe()
```

So my question is, is `fromEvent` function better than the event binding? Is it readable enough? Is it used commonly or do you think it should be used commonly (at least when logic become complex)?

In another words, is it best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be an opinion based question. But in general BOTH are used depending on what you are trying to achive.

- If you are trying to just open a modal on a button click or just do a simple action, the event binding is meant for that.
- If you are chaining rxjs functions and trying to achive a more complex behavior then you can and should use observables and rxjs. And you wouldn't need the formElement ref or anything like that.

BUT you shouldn't use it as the example you provided above with the `fromEvent`. You would probably create a new observable and emit it on the submit event.

ex (html):

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="formSubmit.next(form.value)">
</form>
```

ex (ts):

```
this.formSubmit.pipe(
    takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$),
    tap(() => this.onSubmit()),
    concatMap(() => this.http.post('/api/user', { name })),
    concatMap(() => this.storageSerivce.push(name)),
    catchError(...)
    ...
  )
  .subscribe()
```

Comment: `onSubmit()` pushes data into `users` array and resets the form. Why would you do that before the http succeeds?

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought about, when these practice to use. So RxJS approach is used commonly?

Comment: @j4rey I just updated the example, in reality you wouldn't need `this.unsubscribe$` too in this logic.

Comment: @someApp Yes all the time.

Comment: Why I shouldn't use `fromEvent` function? Why should I create excess `Subject` property when I got solution with exact functionality out of the box? Is it because of exposing access to HTML Element? Why is it bad?

Comment: @someApp `ViewChild` can fail if the element is hidden for example. And I wouldn't say `fromEvent` is bad, it just creates an observable at the end of the day. So just creating the observable yourself would give the same results without `ViewChild`.

Comment: @Zahema I see the point. It is totally make sense. Thanks for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it quite obvious, its event binding. Mainly for 3 reason

- Angular Event binding was created for this exact functionality.
- `fromEvent` is an RxJs feature, which you have to subscribe. And later you have to unsubscribe since it persist, else it creates memory leakage. Note with Angular event binding you don't have to subscribe and unsubscribe.
- Finally, with `fromEvent` you have to pass the DOM element and hence you have to access it using `this.formEl.nativeElement`. With Angular you want to avoid such access/manipulation of DOM elements directly on code, such style are typical of jQuery/Javascript.

Comment: What about the extra async logic, like I described in the example? What if you need to make a http request then on response save some data in IndexedDB or any else storage? What if you want to handle only very last submission and the previous cancel (switchMap operator is ideal for it)? How would you do it with the event binding?

Comment: You would do all that in the event function. Ideally the flow would be: make http call -> pipe additional logic () -> then in subscribe make the UI/application changes like form reset or push object to array which is binding to UI. Note, http call is self-unsubscribing.